# How to skip hostname and move to the next in ssh?

Tags: macos, bash

I have this Bash script that will ssh into Macs based on a .txt file that holds their hostnames.

```
File=/Users/<username>/Desktop/PartitionPermissions.txt
echo \ >> $File
cat Names.txt | xargs -I %Name ssh -n -q <username>@%Name "$(< testscript.sh)" >>        $File
```

However, if one of the hostnames does not resolve (Because the computer is not currently online) it will terminate the script right there instead of moving on to the next hostname in the file. Is there a way to force it to skip to the next hostname instead of completely stopping the script from completing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should loop and not fail, even if ssh fails:

```
File=/Users/<username>/Desktop/PartitionPermissions.txt
echo \ >> $File
while read name; do
    ssh -n -q <username>@$name "$(< testscript.sh)" >> $File
done < Names.txt
```

Although you might want to check that ssh completes, e.g. in the `while` loop instead:

```
if ! ssh -n -q <username>@$name "$(< testscript.sh)" >> $File; then
    echo "ssh for $name failed"
fi
```